# Data from database not being returned in .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

I have published a web application to an IIS web server, but prior to doing this everything was working, and now it is not.

Access to the SQL Server 2008 is via User ID and Password in the connection string Persist Security Info = true. There is no windows authentication or impersonation set on the web.config, and the web application runs on our INTRANET.

The problem I am seeing is that the application loads, but when a part of the application that involves getting some data from the database it fails. Using IDataRecord as part of my mapping of data from the database to a class, the IDataRecord is showing the following:

1) Error_Number Value = 0
2) Error_Message Value = 1

after passing this into a dictionary class to see what is being returned.

Anyone out there who can shed any light on this?

Comment: Can you verify that you can access this database when you directly log onto the IIS web server (i.e., terminal services session), and try connecting say from SSMS or MS Access?

Comment: Can you provide the Exception details you're getting when your code tries to connect?

Comment: will check, but someone else has to log on to do this for me as I do not have direct access myself. But do you have any other thoughts that could help?

Comment: Exception I am getting is that it cannot find the field name that I am mapping from the database to the property in my class

Comment: Can connect, stored proc runs but results are not as expected that are returned. It has error_message and error_number as the column name and not the one I wish to map to

Comment: The issue seems to be around the connection string: running in Visual Studio 2008 - if the connection string does not contain a user id and password but Integrated Security = true then it works, but if I publish this to the web server it won't work and says that there is login problem. On the otherhand if change the connection string to User ID and Password and Persist Security Info = true, then nothing works in visual studio and I get the error I posted earlier.